# How to register MVC4 portable areas and routes in nUnit tests?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nunit, portable-areas

My MVC4 solution contains three projects:

1. Web, an MVC 4 web application
2. MyAccount, a portable area
3. Tests, a class library that leverages nUnit (and moq)

Web's global.asax defines some routes, as does MyAccount (in its implementation of PortableAreaRegistration).

In my nUnit tests, I need to get the entire solution's set of routes. I can get the routes defined in Web using code like:

```
if (RouteTable.Routes.Count == 0)
{
    RouteRegistrationConfigurator.Configure();
    MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

When I try to expand that to include portable areas using this:

```
if (RouteTable.Routes.Count == 0)
{
    var areaRegistration = new MyAccountAreaRegistration();
    var areaRegistrationContext = new AreaRegistrationContext(areaRegistration.AreaName, RouteTable.Routes);
    areaRegistration.RegisterArea(areaRegistrationContext);

    RouteRegistrationConfigurator.Configure();
    MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

I get an InvalidOperationException: "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object." on the `RegisterArea()` call.

Putting this code in either the test itself or in the TestFixtureSetUp method makes no difference to the error.

The `AreaRegistrationContext` constructor has an optional third parameter that is an `object state`. By default, that's null. Giving it an empty object (`new {}` or `new object {}`) doesn't fix the error. I've not been able to find any documentation as to what that `state` object can or should be.

Using an `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` call instead of registering the specific area results in the error message "InvalidOperationException : This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase."

I see examples of these area registration lines being usable in MVC2 projects without this error. Is something different about MVC4 that changes how I should be setting this up?

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution for that? Im looking for it as I have the same problem. Thank you.